# Using onClick in react-virtulized Grid cell/row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm using the `Grid` component from `react-virulized` and need to handle click event at a column cell and row level.
I tried adding an onClick to the `div` returned by my cellRenderer method, but it don't appear to work. Has anyone got this working? See below:

```
_renderCell ({ columnIndex, rowIndex }) {
    // name = getFrom(columnIndex, rowIndex)
    return (
      <div className={'cell'} >
        <input type="text" {name} maxLength={2} onClick={alert(columnIndex)}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you **invoke** the function instead of **referencing** it, so when the DOM is loaded, the alert gets called.To make your code work use the [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method:

```
alert.bind(null,columnIndex); // alert will always have columnIndex's value as the first argument
```

Comment: Yup yup. Or alternately `<input type="text" {name} maxLength={2} onClick={() => alert(columnIndex)}/>`

Comment: Thanks guys. That was a premature question.. :(